# How to echo the decimals?

Tags: php, sql, forms

I have a form in wich i show the numbers from my sql table (ex. 2.39...) like that 2 in one  and 39 in other . The code I use is this:

```
<td><?php echo (int)$row["S1"] ?></td>
<td><?php echo ($row["S1"] - (int)$row["S1"])*100 ?></td>
```

It looks like that:

But it is dificult for me to update the values back to the number in sql table.

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode` to split the string after the dot.

```
$number = explode('.',2.39);

echo $number[0]; // ouptuts 2
echo $number[1]; // ouptuts 39
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode to split the string after the dot.

```
$split = explode('.', $row['S1']);
// integer: $split[0]; decimals: $split[1];
```